# Selenium Java Provar - Why my action moveToElement does not perform

Tags: java, selenium, hover, tooltip

I'm trying to perform moveToElement action using Selnium Java in Provar. 
My imports for actions:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
```

My custom method is:

```
        public void checkContractNumberOnHover() {
        WebDriver driver = provarSeleniumDriver.getWebDriver();
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

        WebElement contract = driver.findElement(By.xpath("MyXpath1"));
        WebElement contractProperNumber = driver.findElement(By.xpath("MyXpath2"));

        Action mouseOverContract = builder.moveToElement(contract).build();
        mouseOverContract.perform();
value");

        assertTrue(contractProperNumber.isDisplayed());

        String contractActualString = contractProperNumber.getText();
        assertTrue(contractActualString.contains("N2019-0001"));        
    }
}
```

My test needs to hover over tooltip and read then compare value (value is visible only while hovering). Hover it seems like my test doesn't even hover over the item at the 1st place. In the log there is info that xpath2 is wrong (there is no element cause tooltip did not show up. I'm trying to use Action like in this tutorial:
https://www.guru99.com/keyboard-mouse-events-files-webdriver.html

P.S my xpaths ok tested multiple times one element is found for each of them. I have no idea why the moveToElemnt action does not even trigger :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put each finding of xpath in `Try -catch--see`. If element not found is coming for `xpath1` as well.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
try{
  WebElement contract = driver.findElement(By.xpath("MyXpath1"));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
syso("print exception"+e.getmessage);
}

WebElement contractProperNumber = driver.findElement(By.xpath("MyXpath2"));
actions.moveToElement(contract).`enter code here`perform();
System.out.println("Done Mouse hover on xpath1");
```

Comment: It seems that locators are fine. I have no idea why this .moveToElement() method simply does not perform :(

Answer (score 1):

There can be applied "a dirty fix": I had such a situation and moving to element twice helped to solve the problem:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).moveToElement(element).perform();
```